# Need to remove quotes inside the array of a string using python

Tags: python, regex

```
input = "'Siva', ['Aswin','latha'], 'Senthil',['Aswin','latha']"
```

expected output:

```
"'Siva', [Aswin,latha], 'Senthil',[Aswin,latha]"
```

I have used positive lookbehind and lookahead but its not working.

pattern

```
(?<=\[)\'+(?=\])
```

Comment: Your pattern will match `[']` or contain multiple `'`

Comment: What are you *actually trying to accomplish here?*

Comment: Can you have a string like `"'Siva', ['Aswin','latha'], 'Senthil',['[Aswin','[latha]']" `?

Answer (score 2):

We can use `re.sub` here with a callback lambda function:

```py
inp = "'Siva', ['Aswin','latha'], 'Senthil',['Aswin','latha']"
output = re.sub(r'\[.*?\]', lambda x: x.group().replace("'", ""), inp)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
'Siva', [Aswin,latha], 'Senthil',[Aswin,latha]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
input = "'Siva', ['Aswin','latha'], 'Senthil',['Aswin','latha']"


print(re.sub(r"(?<=\[).*?(?=\])", lambda val: re.sub(r"'(\w+?)'", r"\1", val.group()), input))

# 'Siva', [Aswin,latha], 'Senthil',[Aswin,latha]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this if you don't want to `import re`:

```py
X = eval("'Siva', ['Aswin','latha'], 'Senthil',['Aswin','latha']")
Y = []
for x in X:
    Y.append(f"[{', '.join(x)}]" if isinstance(x, list) else f"'{x}'")
print(", ".join(Y))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.findall` with an alternation pattern to find either fragments between `]` and `[`, or otherwise non-single-quote characters, and then join the fragments together with `''.join`:

```
''.join(re.findall(r"[^\]]*\[|\][^\[]*|[^']+", input))
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/ClassicFrostyBookmark

This is generally more efficient than using `re.sub` with a callback since there is overhead involved in making a callback for each match.